# pandoc Jupyter-to-Latex | How to size images?

Tags: html, image, markdown, jupyter, pandoc

Within Jupyter markdown cells, jpeg images can be referenced like  or like .  Then convert from Jupyter to LaTex.  The former approach does not allow for image sizing.  The latter approach results in ignored HTML.

Is there a way, perhaps with a lua filter, to capture the  with the sizing information and transform it to \includegraphics[width=……,height=……]{images/image.jpg} ?  Or is there some other preferred way to size images?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right solution is to just display jpeg's from code cells rather than from markdown cells, like this: display_jpeg(file="img.jpg", width=400).  pandoc's normal behavior then just converts the sized image to \includegraphics[width=..., height=...]{images/...}